# Passing `this` to function that accesses property on it gives undefined?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm trying to pass in `this` to have access to the parent properties. I'm stumped. Am I missing something completely obvious? The code compiles properly but it's not returning the parent as expected. I've used this pattern before but in vanilla Javascript. Could it have to do with the functions being declared as `var`s by CoffeeScript?

```
Model = (parent) ->
    @view = parent.view
    console.log @view # undefined?
    return

View = (parent) ->
    @model = parent.model
    console.log @model # undefined?
    return

ViewModel = ->
    @view = new View @
    @model = new Model @
    return

vm = new ViewModel()
```

Comment: When you construct `View`, `@model` will be `undefined` as it has not been created yet.

Comment: Is there a pattern I can research in which both `view` and `model` would be available to each other?

Comment: The first `console.log` (in `Model`) does not log undefined.  Maybe you can share the vanilla js you've used and we can help you find the differences?

Comment: are you sure you don't mean to be using the `class` keyword in Coffeescript for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are passing the reference of the parent but cacheing inside the object as undefined when you assign `@view = parent.view`. if view is undefined on parent at that moment, it will be undefined into the future. I think instead what you want is this:

```
class Model
    constructor: (@parent) ->

    view: -> @parent.view

class View
    constructor: (@parent) ->

    model: -> @parent.model

class ViewModel
    constructor: ->
      console.log 'this', @
      @view = new View @
      @model = new Model @
      #console.log 'model', @model.view()
      #console.log 'view', @view.model()

vm = new ViewModel()

console.log vm.model.view()
console.log vm.view.model()
```

working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8hnfkarx/

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. Looks like I have quite a bit of reading up to do!

Comment: nothing too crazy here, you can a background on it here: http://coffeescript.org/#classes